# Confusion on why the value of SSE is lower when a cluster looks distorted on the plot

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, k-means

I have a dataset of shape `(29088, 11)`. When I apply the Kmeans where K=2 I get the following plot:

[image]

Cluster C0 has 8554 points (in blue) and cluster C1 has 20534 points (in red). I am surprised that the value of Sum Squared Error (SSE) for C0 is smaller than the value of SSE for C1 as C0 (in blue) is noticeably distorted which does not make sense having lower SSE than the densely contained C1?

Thank you

Comment: SSE stands for "sum of squared errors". C1 has 2.4 times more points so the total error is higher. But C1 has only 1.7 higher SSE than C0, so your intuition is correct. Instead look at the mean squared error *MSE = SSE / n* or the root mean squared error *RMSE = sqrt(MSE)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSE for cluster 0 is $\approx 3.285$, and for cluster 1, it is $\approx 2.324$. It makes sense to have a lower MSE for the densely packed cluster. The SSE, is *sum* of squared errors and it also depends on the number of points. If the cluster 1 has a lot more points, even if the the distortion is quite small, SSE can be bigger than the cluster 0.